# How to increase laravel controller method execution time?

Tags: php, laravel, execution

I want to increase execution time of my controller method to 5 minutes . I searched but many times I found just one working idea that is increase the execution time in php.ini file but I do not want this I want to increase the execution time in laravel controller for one method only. Can any one tell me how I do that???
I tried many code one example is given below

```
public function postGetEvents1(){

    set_time_limit(600);

    //other code
```

}

Answer (score 10):

This should work for you, if you want to set higher execution time limit for just one method:

```
public function postGetEvents1(){

    // Get default limit
    $normalTimeLimit = ini_get('max_execution_time');

    // Set new limit
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 600); 

    //other code

    // Restore default limit
    ini_set('max_execution_time', $normalTimeLimit); 

    return;
}
```

Comment: if I want to set the time for 2 min then I have to input 120 instead of 600 is thar right?

Comment: Yes, time is in seconds here.

Comment: ok thanks and how I changed safe mode in script? because i don't want messing with php.ini

Comment: I wonder did you try to use the code and does it work? Because safe mode feature was removed since PHP 5.6, this code should work without any additional settings.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin: I don't need this for now. But out of curiosity, where did this code should be called? In constructor method of the controller/

Comment: Your original question was about increasing execution time of one method, so just run this code in that method. ;)